# Single word for Time off in lieu

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any single word describing Time off in lieu ?

This is to add section in our employee portal to users to add Time in lieu they did and time off they took.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"comp time", short for "Compensatory Time Off" See https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/pay-administration/fact-sheets/compensatory-time-off/

Comment: Yep, sometimes written "CTO".

Comment: +1 So if a user works certain hours to take this time off in future, would we call it Compensatory Time off as well ? Thanks

Comment: That's generally the way it works, yes...the time off compensates for the extra work already done.